# Don't compile if function failed to be inlined in C++

Tags: c++, function, optimization, inline

Is it possible to force compiler (CLang/GCC/MSVC) to throw compile error whenever forced-inline function failed to be inlined for any reason?

Imagine next code:

[Following code in online compiler!](https://godbolt.org/z/K7acx9)

```
#include <iostream>

inline __attribute__((always_inline)) int f(int i) {
    if (i <= 0)
        return 0;
    return f(i - 1) + f(i - 2) + i;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << f(10) << std::endl;
}
```

Because of two recursive self-calls function f() failed to be inlined although was instructed to be inlined always by `__attribute__((always_inline))`. You can see in assembler by link above that there is instruction `call f(int)`, meaning that function was not inlined.

Is it possible anyhow for the code above to throw compile error (in CLang/MSVC/GCC) because it failed to inline? Maybe some compile-time `static_assert(...)` expression can be used for that?

I expect that there can be other reasons for non-inlining, both due properties of function code and due to properties of code on caller side. So in general probably you can't be sure in advance that your function is inlined in 100% of all calls. Hence solution to my question will be useful.

Also interested in solving same question for the case of lambda-functions inlining.

Answer (score 2):

you can set a warning level in visual studio to fail compilation on all warnings.
There is no Assertion to check for inline failure.

[warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-option-warning-level?view=msvc-160)

A better answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494399/would-c-exception-stops-function-from-being-inlined)

You can use -Winline in GCC and switch on specific flag inorder to consider warning into error.

'[-Werror](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html)=
Make the specified warning into an errors. The specifier for a warning is appended, for example -Werror=switch turns the warnings controlled by -Wswitch into errors. This switch takes a negative form, to be used to negate -Werror for specific warnings, for example -Wno-error=switch makes -Wswitch warnings not be errors, even when -Werror is in effect. You can use the -fdiagnostics-show-option option to have each controllable warning amended with the option which controls it, to determine what to use with this option.'

Comment: Do you know if this kind of non-inlined warning command option exists for any compiler (CLang/GCC/MSVC)? Also do you know if it is possible to tell compiler to treat only this one warning as error to stop compiling?

Comment: -Winline is available in GCC , You can use -Werror  flag to turn warnings into error  -like :           -Werror=

Comment: Update the answer

Comment: I expect that all you wrote about warnings and command options is related only to CLang/GCC? Do you know same command options for MSVC too? I need to enable compile error only for inline warnings. Also maybe you know how to enable such error only for one specific function, not all `inline` functions in code?

Comment: Anyway a good answer, I'm UpVoting! Would be nice if you cover in your answer all CLang/GCC/MSVC compilers. Also would be nice if you know (and write) solution to mark only single specific function to throw compile error. Maybe there is some pragma to apply `-Winline` only to one specific function.

Comment: @Arty For MSVC those would be warnings [C4710](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-4-c4710?view=msvc-160) and [C4714](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-4-c4714?view=msvc-160). The latter applies to functions declared as `__forceinline` only, which gives you finer control over what triggers it.

Comment: @dxiv Maybe you know how to apply in all of CLang/GCC/MSVC one custom warning/error to just single function or block of code lines. Maybe there is some pragma in all of these compilers (different for different compilers) e.g. you mark block of lines at start with `#pragma enable_warning_start("inline")` and at end `#pragma enable_warning_end("inline")`.

Comment: @Arty Don't know of such facility, so I'll leave that to those more familiar with CLang and GCC.